# How to load a Google AD code in background in my asp.net webpage?

Tags: asp.net

I embed a google AD code in my asp.net webpage, it causes my webpage to load slow.

Is there way to load the Google AD code in background? I hope to display other content of webpage first and display google AD last.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "pub-5823168326939016";
    /* HiCalc 234x60 On 10-10-22 */
    google_ad_slot = "1050696847";
    google_ad_width = 234;
    google_ad_height = 60;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Comment: how many of this ads do you have on your pages, and in witch places ? (on top/bottom/middle etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can.

Solution 1: don't directly include AD code to the page, but fetch it when page is loaded using javascript/AJAX (jQuery.get() will work just fine) and insert it in the page. I have tested, and the code loaded by ajax techniques gets executed when added to page DOM (Document Object Model - page content).

Solution 2: change the AD code, just surround it with some content element, like <textarea>(AD code goes here)</textarea>. Then, when the page loads, run a javascript code, which fetches the TextArea content and adds it to page DOM.

Note: I am not 100% sure this will work as expected on all the browsers, but it should.

Note2: I am not 100% sure what rules are forced by Google AdSense, and maybe this workaround violates some of them... But I think it is ok :-)

**EDIT**:

Here is code for the page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.get('/AdCode.aspx', null, function (data) {
            jQuery('.ad-code-container').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="d1" class="ad-code-container">
</div>
```

Here is code for AdCode.aspx file:

```
<@ Page Language="C#" Leave here whatever your app has %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google_ad_client = "pub-5823168326939016";
    google_ad_slot = "1050696847";
    google_ad_width = 234;
    google_ad_height = 60;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!
1. Why did you want to add the "<@ Page Language="C#" Leave here whatever your app has %>" to AdCode.aspx ?
2. Are you sure thta your code don't violates google policy 100% ?

Comment: Please see Note 2. Using of this is completely on your responsibility. Personally I use ad code the way it is provided by Google.

Comment: Thanks!
1. Why did you want to add the "<@ Page Language="C#" Leave here whatever your app has %>" to AdCode.aspx ?
2. I think your code is same as using iframe, right?

Comment: 1. I am not sure if the aspx file will still work without <@page> directive, isn't that required? 2. In some sense - yes - because it loads AD code aside from the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" type="text/javascript"></script
```

you need to use word async in script code to load ad async